# Accessing Calling Scope in Module Method

Tags: ruby, scope, reference

I'm making a little debug tool to get the arguments passed into a method as follows:

```
Class bar
  def foo(a,b,c)
    Debug.get_arguments()
    ### do stuff
  end
end

module Debug
  def get_arguments
    method(__method__).parameters.map { |arg| [arg[1],eval(arg[1].to_s)] }.to_h
  end
end
```

Currently, it returns and empty hash '{}' while I'd like it to return {a: x, b: y, c: z} (the arguments of foo along with the values).

Is there something like __calling_method__ or __parent_method__? Otherwise, I'd have to put this debugging code in every method.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do what you would like.  The scope gate is preventing you from accessing variables outside of the method scope.  You could try to bypass that by defining your methods in a way that does not generate scope gates but I had no success with doing that.
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-scope-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this done by using `eval` to evaluate a string of code in the current scope.

Note that there were some errors with your code that I've fixed:

- in `Class bar`, the capitalization was wrong
- you're calling `Debug.get_arguments`, so `get_arguments` should be a class method

Note that I'm loading awesome_print just to show the output more clearly; the code is not dependent on it.

The script (test.rb):

```
require 'awesome_print'

class Bar
  def foo(a,b,c)
    eval Debug.get_arguments
  end
end

module Debug
  def self.get_arguments
    "method(__method__).parameters.map { |arg| [arg[1],eval(arg[1].to_s)] }.to_h"
  end
end

ap Bar.new.foo 1,2,3
```

Calling the script:

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

Prints:

```
{
    :a => 1,
    :b => 2,
    :c => 3
}
```

This shows that `eval` works even when nested, which is cool.